# Advise request python env issue after upgrade to 16.04.1

Tags: python, django, pip, ubuntu-16.04

After I upgraded my OS to stable version of 16.04.1 I found that my local django version dropped to 1.8.7 when i was using 1.9+. first reaction was to use `pip install --upgrade django==1.9.7`  but it gave me that pip is not found.. same as easy_install. After checking I can see that i have files in usr/local/bin/*

```
taras@taras-Laptop:/usr/local/bin$ ls
charm         django-admin.py   easy_install-3.4  pip2    pip3.4       sqlformat       wstorm
code          django-admin.pyc  idea              pip2.7  pip.pyc      virtualenv
django-admin  easy_install      pip               pip3    __pycache__  virtualenv-3.5
```

when my all files lies here: `usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*`

Please advise best solution for me to fix it(by saying fix it i mean to use my old python2.7 stuff by default)

I was thinking about adding some env variable? but im not sure so i decided to ask first.

Thanks

Comment: ¿Could you specify which OS are you using? and have you tried to use [virtualenvs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) ?

Comment: OS - ubuntu 16.04.1; I haven't tried virtualenvs yet. I really want to know why its not working as it is now and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the upgrade Python was replaced with a newer version. `pyc` files that might work with the old version might no longer work with the new version. So you can't expect them to work. You might try to remove all your `pyc` files and your `__pycache__` directories, but, really, your system is a mess. It would be far better to remove everything Python-related in `/usr/local`.

This is exactly the kind of problems you avoid with `virtualenv`, about which I have an introduction called [virtualenv demystified](http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/).

Comment: What i will achieve by deleting everything Py-related in /usr/local/ ?

Comment: Your system will be clean of the mess, and you will re-install the things you need using `pip` (and, preferably, `virtualenv`).

Comment: its kind of tough decision to make(delete all python related files). But I agree that all should be sorted properly using virtualenv.